# Error adding dependency to ASP.NET 5 (VS2015)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've just created my first ASP.Net 5 app and I ran into a problem installing the reference for Entity Framework.
I added the dependency to project.json :

```
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
```

and the error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  NU1001  The
>   dependency EntityFramework.Commands >= 7.0.0-rc1-final could not be
>   resolved. C:\code\VS2015\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.xproj    C:\code\VS2015\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\project.json 10

I'm inside a corporate network so maybe this is a proxy issue?

Comment: Did u try the command line :  dnu restore ?

Comment: try reinstalling `EntityFramework` from `nuget` packages.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the machine.config in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config worked for me

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
<proxy usesystemdefault="True"/>
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```